# Google Cloud Dataflow (Apache Beam) - Can I use SideInputs with TextIO.write?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

It looks so far we can use `sideInputs` only for `DoFn` to use side input when processing each input line.

Is there any way to utilize the input with `TextIO.Write` ?
In my case,

```
    outputTuple.get(deadletterTag)
        .apply("Write to deadletter files",
            TextIO.write().to(String.format("gs://dataflow-xxx/deadletter/%s/", uniqueID))
                .withSuffix(".csv")
                .withHeader(csvHeader)
        ).withSideInputs(csvHeaderView);
```

I have a csv header info as a `PCollectionView<String>` (obtained in a prior process by using `Combine.globally` and `AsSingletonView`) and want to somehow extract the header string and assign it into `withHeader`, but not sure if it's possible because there is no `ProcessContext` appears.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to do this as of Apache Beam 2.2.0 and earlier.

I have created [BEAM-2771](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2771) which tracks a general feature which could enable this.

Comment: Understood, it's sad but anyway thank you so much for the answer!